# Why Firebase.auth.getUses dow not support filter?

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication

please check my code below
and please help me to tackle this issue~

when I use FireBase.Auth.getUses()

I only set data such as
getUses([userId:'dddd'])

but I want to getUsers( "userId" contain "@hayan.com" )

```
getAuth()
  .getUser(uid)
  .then((userRecord) => {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    console.log(`Successfully fetched user data: ${userRecord.toJSON()}`);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('Error fetching user data:', error);
  });
```

Is There a way to tackle this?

Thanks in advance

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to filter the user data on the type of criteria you seem to want. The only options are:

- to [list all users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users) and then filter in your application code, which probably won't scale very well.
- store a list of the user details elsewhere (typically in a cloud-hosted database) and perform your query on that.

---

If you're looking to load a specific user when you know their complete email address, the second code sample in the documentation on [getting user data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data) show how to do that:

```
getAuth()
  .getUserByEmail(email)
  .then((userRecord) => {
    ...
  })
```